# How to apply shopping cart rule for single product?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

we want a discount to be applied when user add to cart 10 M size t-shirts, 10 L size t-shirts and 5 XL size t-shirts (same product) - so total quantity is 25. & we want to give discount only for the product whose quality is 25 or greater?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create "Shopping Cart Price Rule" with condition on "Quantity in Cart". Does it help you?

[image]